# issue with the empty `ListView`

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm having an issue with the empty `ListView` where I want to show the message only when there is some data present in database.... but Im getting the error at this line

`android:id="@*android:id/list"`
     and
`android:id="@*android:id/empty"`

Error is:

```
 Illegal resource reference: @*android resources are private and not always present
```

MY code is in this way.....

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@*android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:listSelector="@*android:color/transparent" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
        android:divider="@drawable/line" 
        android:dividerHeight="3.0dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@*android:id/empty" 
        android:textColor="#ff777777" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="No data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

please help me on this...

Comment: Remove the *s to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code by this

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:listSelector="@*android:color/transparent" 
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
    android:divider="@drawable/line" 
    android:dividerHeight="3.0dip" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@android:id/empty" 
    android:textColor="#ff777777" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:text="No data" />
```

also use the below code for your array list for a message for empty array list

```
if(arrayList.isEmpty())
    {
        // do your message code here
    }
```

Comment: It worked #Ameer... now im not geting any error... thanku for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Remove asterik (*) prior id's,

here is your updated layout

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
        android:divider="@drawable/line" 
        android:dividerHeight="3.0dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/empty" 
        android:textColor="#ff777777" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="No data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you have

```
@*android
```

change it to

```
@android
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
<LinearLayout>
      <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/list" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:listSelector="@*android:color/transparent" 
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
            android:divider="@drawable/line" 
            android:dividerHeight="3.0dip" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/empty" 
            android:textColor="#ff777777" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="No data" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "*" from your layout code and try below code:

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:listSelector="@*android:color/transparent" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
        android:divider="@drawable/line" 
        android:dividerHeight="3.0dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/empty" 
        android:textColor="#ff777777" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="No data" />
</LinearLayout>
```